# Give the number and fill the xth (x is the number) item in a list with '1',keep others empty

Tags: python

for example, I have a list of data like this:

```
['81', '88', '99', '124', '144', '145', '216', '223', '225', '227', '231', '232', '233', '236', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '244', '245', '246', '247', '248', '249', '250', '251', '253', '254', '256', '257', '259', '260', '261', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268', '269', '270', '271', '272', '273', '274', '275', '276', '278', '279', '280', '281', '284', '285', '288', '296', '299', '304']
```

and I created a list, which contains 365 of ' ' by using  `julianList=[" "] *365`

Now, what I need to do is change the xth(x is number) of item in juLianList into '1'

I use the following code

```
    julianList=[" "] *365
    EjulianList=list(enumerate(julianList))
##    print(EjulianList)
    print(julianList[2])
    for i in range(len(julian)):
        for j in range(len(EjulianList)):
            if julian[i]==EjulianList[j][0]:
                julianList[j]='1'
    print(julianList)
```

but still get a list with 365 ' '
like

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

what's wrong with it?

Comment: do you mean `julianList = ['1' if str(i) in data else ' ' for i, x in enumerate(range(365))]`?

Comment: Is `julian` the list at the start of your question?

Comment: In fact `julianList = ['1' if str(i) in julian else ' ' for i, x in enumerate(range(365))]` is what I want

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The key words in this case are minimal (is reading a CSV file relevant?) and verifiable (what is your desired output given certain inputs?).

Comment: In that case, it would be more efficient to make `julian` a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two (obvious) ways to do it.

The first, initializes the list and *corrects* some of its entries depending on the contents of `data` list.

```
data = ['1', '7', '8']
julianList = [" "] * 10
for i in map(int, data):
    julianList[i] = '1'
print(julianList)  # -> [' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ']
```

---

The second, is a list comprehension that creates the correct input as the list is created.

```
data = ['1', '7', '8']
# optionally to speed up the membership tests do : data = set(data)
julianList = ['1' if str(i) in data else ' ' for i, _ in enumerate(range(10))]
print(julianList)  # -> [' ', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', ' ']
```

*<sup>Note that I scaled the problem down for visualization purposes.</sup>*

The first method is preferable in your case, because of the costly membership tests required by the second approach. To improve on those, you can cast `data` into `set` before running the list-comprehension by doing `data = set(data)`.

---

---

It would however be even better if you would just create a dictionary that contains your `'1'`s and just use `.get()` to get the `' '`s too<sup>kudos @JonClemens</sup>.

```
julianDict = dict.fromkeys(map(int, data), '1')
```

with the `dict` in place, you can do:

```
print(julianDict.get(7, ' '))  # -> '1'
print(julianDict.get(3, ' '))  # -> ' '
```

This 3rd option is by far the most efficient but does not provide you with a list. You can use it to built one though if you **really** need it.

```
julianInsistsOnTheList = [julianDict.get(x, ' ') for x in range(365)]
```

Comment: So why can't I use two 'for' loop to do it?

Comment: think of two for loops as saying *I want to iterate over all contents of list `data`, for every position in list `julianList`*. This is just not what you want.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis not sure about a `set`... looks to me like using a `dict` would be more useful here.... `julian = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 366), '')` then `julian.update((int(k), '1') for k in data)`... OP might want to materialise a list at the end but can still use it easily enough for access/retrieval as a dict.

Comment: @JonClements This seems like a very nice, no-so-obvious solution. I would upvote that.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis probably even better if an actual list isn't required... just `d = dict.fromkeys(map(int, data), '1')` and then just use `d.get(whatever, '')` to retrieve things... treating it like a sparse structure...

Comment: @Ev.Kounis or... the really horrible `list(map(lambda L, J=dict.fromkeys(map(int, data), '1'): J.get(L, ' '), range(1, 366)))` to create a list :p

Comment: @JonClements This does look as if someone has been trying really hard to be abnoxious but it taught me that you can define (local) variables inside a `lambda`.. Wow.

Comment: Like I said - it's horrible and I wouldn't stand for it being in production code and it was more a joke than anything trying to pretend to be a suggestion to a proper solution... but yeah... glad it's given you an "TIL" moment :)

Answer (score 1):

enumerate generates tuples, where the first is a number, in `julian` the elements are strings, therefore `if julian[i] == EjulianList[j][0]` is never true.

Simply, convert your numbers into `int`.

By the way, lists in Python are 0-based, so you have to shift the day's by one:

```
with open('data.csv') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    julian = [int(c) for c in next(reader)]
julianList = [" "] * 365
for day in julian:
    julianList[day - 1] = "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact

```
julianList = ['1' if str(i) in julian else ' ' for i, x in enumerate(range(365))]
```

in the comment is what I want